# Median for multiple columns start Start_With same letters?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, median

I want to calculate the medeian for several columns based on what letters each column begins with, creating a new column.

I know the way to do this for mean using dplyr and an example like that shown below:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, IVMean = rowMeans(select(df, starts_with("IV")), na.rm = TRUE))
```

But how is this possible for median?

I have tried a number of ways including select then mutate but having no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `rowMedians` after converting to `matrix`

```
library(matrixStats)
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, IVMedian = rowMedians(as.matrix(select(df, 
         starts_with("IV"))), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-ouptut

```
   IV1 IV2 IV3 col4 IVMedian
1   2   4   1    1        2
2   3   8   3    2        3
3   4   9   4    3        4
```

---

Or this can be done in `rowwise` with `c_across`

```
df %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(IVMedian = median(c_across(starts_with('IV')))) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 5
    IV1   IV2   IV3  col4 IVMedian
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     2     4     1     1        2
2     3     8     3     2        3
3     4     9     4     3        4
```

---

Or use `pmap` (from `purrr`)

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(IVMedian = pmap_dbl(select(., starts_with('IV')), 
           ~ median(c(...))))
  IV1 IV2 IV3 col4 IVMedian
1   2   4   1    1        2
2   3   8   3    2        3
3   4   9   4    3        4
```

---

Or in `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
df$IVMedian <-  dapply(gvr(df, vars = '^IV'), MARGIN = 1, FUN = fmedian)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(IV1 = c(2, 3, 4), IV2 = c(4, 8, 9), 
   IV3 = c(1, 3, 4), col4 = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more `dplyr` friendly way would be to use [rowwise](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html) and [c_across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/c_across.html?q=c_across#ref-usage):

```
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(IVMedian = median(c_across(starts_with('IV'))))
```

`rowwise` allows you to do row-by-row computation instead of computing the median of the whole dataframe at once.
`c_across` helps you select several columns in a dataframe using dplyr keywords like `starts_with()`, `contains()`, or `matches()`.